# What does it mean if a "Unknown Device Installed" message appears?

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit

I came back to my computer, and the following message had appeared:

[image]

I'm wondering what reasons could there be for this? Is there a log I can check to see what was actually installed?

Comment: You could try looking in Device Manager (Control Panel, or right-click on "Computer" and hit "Manage").

Comment: Event Viewer might show something useful.

Answer (score 0):

open Device Manager, look at the properties of the device and look for the Hardware IDs. Now go to a [PCI database](http://www.pcidatabase.com/) and search which device this is.